# Android- How to extend AppCompatActivity() in an Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, onactivityresult, appcompatactivity

I got an `adapter` and I got an action which open a "app camera", then I capture the image. And from here it got to execute a function called `onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)`, but I can't `override` the method because I can't extend AppCompatActivity().

Any help?

Comment: which method you want to be override?

Comment: You should start and handle the intent from the adapters' parent activity, then update your list and call notifyDataSetChanged(); on adapter (don't forget to cast it) still from the host activity

Answer (score 1):

You can't, in Java classes can't inherit from two classes at the same time. Only one. Considering your adapter already `extends RecyclerView.Adapter` then you can't.

**The recommended approach is to use callback**. A callback is an `interface` that is `implements` on the host activity or fragment and pass as an argument to the other class (the adapter on this case). Your adapter will hold a reference to the callback, so when the view is clicked then the reference will be called triggering the implementation on the activity or fragment.

You can see a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32032990/4017501)

1. When the click happens, from the activity start the intent to the camera
2. After the photo is taken inside `onActivityResult` on the activity pass the result to the adapter
3. The adapter need a method for receiving the result, it should be something like this

```
public void addPhoto(SomeObject object){
    yourData.add(object);
    notifyDataseChanged();
}
```

4. The code inside `onActivityResult` should be something like this

```
SomeObject objet = data... //you have to get the data and transform it to your format
adaper.addPhoto(object)
```